# HTML5 Placeholder Text Adding Width In Safari Causing Scrollbars And Flickering

Tags: css, html

In both Safari and Chrome, the `placeholder` attribute seems to add invisible width, causing horizontal scroll-bars and a flicker-like rendering when the window is re-sized horizontally.

`overflow: hidden;` can be applied to the parent element to curb the issue. However, it clips my form field focus effects.

Is there a way to use certain vendor prefixes values to prevent this such as `::-webkit-input-placeholder {}` or some other way?

When the attribute is added to the form input, a horizontal scroll-bar flickers when re-sized horizontally on a webkit browser. Specifically, what style is triggering this behavior? And how do I prevent or override this behavior!?

Comment: Any love out there? I guess it's Sunday. Granted there are quite abit of styles inherited as I am using a grid system, but if anyone can point me in the right direction using FireBug or any other advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome and haven't experienced the flickering?  Are you by chance using and CSS3 transitions or animations?

Comment: No, I stripped out all CSS except input[type="text"] { width: 100%; }.  I have tested the link I provided above on all major browsers both PC and Mac OSX. The horizontal sidebar appears and disappears quickly when resizing the browser window horizontally.This normally may not be a huge deal, but I am working on a responsive design and the mobile viewport can essentially become "curtained" with my grid system.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of safari on a mbp without having problems

Comment: @Daniel Kurz. I have Safari + MBP too and I definitely see it! It is subtle on the link I provided, so you will need to slowly move resize the window horizontally left then right and repeat. Again, not a big deal on the link I provided, but when used on a "real layout" it is a big deal!

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129406
This may be of some help

Comment: I just copied the "computed styles" from Safari's web inspector with the placeholder attribute and without the attribute and pasted them side by side in an Excel spreadsheet and tested to see if there are any differences in the values ... and they all match!

Comment: For the record the best solution I came up with was to use an overflow: hidden declaration on the form's parent (or ancestor) element. In my case I targeted the meat of the document, an element with the "main role" [role="main"]. That way my form focus styles are not clipped!

Comment: Just a side note: This problem also causes mobile Safari to mess up the body width on orientation change when `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` is specified. `    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` "fixes" this, but the problem persists on desktop Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many input elements have default padding. When you state `width: 100%`, it causes the element to be width 100% + padding. To prevent the padding from increasing the width simply use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: Yes, I also started altering the box model for from elements after reading an article by Paul Irish. I am not into applying to all elements as te article mentions but using a selector like .form > * { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;} seems alright. Probably not the most performant selector, but the best solution I have come across! http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your site in Chrome and Safari, but it doesn’t seem to be having the issue you mentioned. However, your top image is overflowing to the top because you sat the overflow to hidden and you didn’t set a top-margin for your header. So, I went ahead and created that margin:

```
 #header img {
  margin-top: 50px;
 }
```

and that solved the problem. I wish I could post an image.