# Mobile Safari - changing from horizontal to vertical view - strange behavior of body

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, responsive-design

When testing my responsive webpage in browsers by resizing the window and using simulators, everything was fine. Now I've just tested the page on my real iPhone 4S with strange results.

When loading the page in vertical view, everything is good, switching to horizontal view is also not a problem. 
But when I turn the phone again so that it enters vertical view again, something strange happens. The vertical version is displayed, but it seems that the `body` does not properly resize. I get a big empty area on the right and a vertical scrollbar, while the elements on the webpage are displayed on the left. Screenshots:

**Vertical #1**
[image]

**Horizontal**
[image]

**Vertical #2**
[image]

This is the CSS code I have on my body (Note: I am still working on that project, so the colors and the font is only temporarily written like that):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: grey;
    color: black;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
}
```

And I also use em based media queries, like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 30em) {
   /* Stuff */
}
```

Inside the media queries I don't change anything on the body.

In the head of my HTML file I have

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Some debugging showed me, that the `body` element resizes correctly, but the `html` element does not.

Do you have any idea what could cause that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured this out! See this Question, it's the exact problem I am having.
[HTML5 Placeholder Text Adding Width In Safari Causing Scrollbars And Flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791013/html5-placeholder-text-adding-width-in-safari-causing-scrollbars-and-flickering)

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```

try adding css:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation:portrait),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)  and (orientation:portrait)
```

and,

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation:landscape),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)  and (orientation:landscape)
```

for retina displays.

maybe this link can help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Ah sorry, that was stupid from me. I forgot to mention that I already have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`in the HTML head. I just tried it with `orientation:portrait` and `orientation:landscape` but without any luck. Please see the edit I made to my initial post.

Comment: @Sven <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" /> this should work for 100%, try :)

Comment: Well, using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` it works, but as soon as I add `, initial-scale=1` it breaks. Do you have any idea why? I have also tried it with a comma instead of a semicolon.

Comment: @sven <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" /> this work for me

Comment: Thank you, but for me this isn't working. Do you have any special CSS declarations regarding the `body` and the `html` element?

Comment: @sven in your situation i will use 

  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%!important;
    outline: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-color: grey;
    color: black;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

and

 #container {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        height: auto !important;
        bottom:0;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;}